# Вывод Twig-массива через intenger-ключ

Tags: twig

Существует массив данных для int значений, куда я не могу адекватно вставить ключ как обычно.

```
public function dataChange(): Response {
        $tmp = [
            '-10' => '2.0%',
            '-9' => '5.2%',
            '-8' => '7.6%',
            '-7' => '11.8%',
            '-6' => '14.8%',
    ];
    return $this->render('view.html.twig', [
        'tmp'=> $tmp
    ]);
```

В результате нужно выводить данные от самого массива при использовании формулы.

```
    {% if item.details.power - 10 >= 10 %}
      {% set variablePower1 = 50.0 %}
    {% elseif %}
      {% set variablePower1 = -8 %}
      {% tmp.variablePower1 %} // условно
```

Как подобное можно сделать без ошибки?
Я не являюсь полноценным разработчиком, но все документации прочитал. Подобного не нашел, если есть документация на пример - буду раз ознакомиться, либо с объяснением как это все работает